# keep toolbars from disappearing in pop-up windows in Firefox

Tags: firefox, printing, popups

Sometimes, a popup window will remove some of your browser controls like your Menubar, preventing you from using features like print preview.

Normally, you can use the "alt" key to bring up your firefox menu - but if you try it in a new pop-up window, it might be blocked.

Answer (score 0):

You can change this behavior in firefox's about:config, as described here:
http://kb.mozillazine.org/Prevent_websites_from_disabling_new_window_features

This will prevent overzealous web developers from controlling what you can do with a pop-up window, such as hiding the menubar, scrolling, re-sizing, etc.

Setting a value to "true" prevents the website from overriding you.